Issue with Dell U2412M Daisy-Chaining: Resolution and Refresh Rate Problems
I am having problems with a multi-monitor setup with daisy-chaining and the Dell U2412M monitor connected via a BenQ dock. The monitor is not recognized correctly when connecting the BenQ dock to my laptop, so it stays black. Although it is displayed in the settings, it does not show the correct resolution and refresh rate, although it worked perfectly when connected directly via HDMI. Despite enabling MST on the BenQ monitor and checking all connections, the Dell monitor remains stuck at a resolution of 1024x768 and a refresh rate of 60 Hz without being able to adjust this in the system settings. Here is a detailed breakdown of the setup and troubleshooting steps:
Setup:
Laptop (USB-C) → BenQ Dock
BenQ Dock (DisplayPort) → BenQ Monitor
BenQ Monitor (DisplayPort) → Dell U2412M
Mac mini (HDMI) → BenQ Monitor
MST (Multi-Stream Transport) is enabled on the BenQ monitor.
Both monitors support Daisy-Chaining.
Key Issues:
Dell U2412M shows incorrect resolution and refresh rate in settings on laptop:
Stuck at 1024x768 @ 60 Hz (it should support 1920x1200 @ 60 Hz).
No option to select the correct resolution or refresh rate through Windows Display Settings.
Monitor initially worked but now shows "Input Timing Not Supported" error:
The monitor no longer recognizes the proper resolution and displays a message: "The current input timing is not supported by the monitor display."
Alternative HDMI connection works:
When I connect the Dell monitor separately via HDMI, it displays the correct resolution. However, this is not a permanent solution since the HDMI port is needed for another device (Mac mini).
Windows settings show no available options to adjust the refresh rate:
The drop-down for refresh rate only shows 60 Hz without any other options, even though the BenQ monitor (in the same chain) runs at 59.95 Hz.
Tested connections:
I tried using the Dell monitor directly connected via mini DisplayPort to DisplayPort, but it was not detected in that configuration.
Request:
Looking for any advice or solutions to:
Force the correct resolution and refresh rate for the Dell U2412M.
Resolve the issue where the display is no longer recognized correctly through Daisy-Chaining.
